# A basic question about light curves

Tags: amateur-observing, light-curve, tess

I'm new here, so if I've done anything wrong, please let me know.

I've been taking a look at some photometry data collected from TESS, and I encountered this light curve:

[image: light curve]

(please ignore the blue and orange lines, I was trying to run some statistical analysis on the data)

I haven't seen a light curve this curvy before, and I was wondering what this was indicative of.

I was also wondering about the spike at around time 1326, would this potentially be an outlier?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the curve in a smaller range arounf 1326? My first impression is that this is a spotted star, with a rotation period of around 5 days and that the feature you have identified is a flare. A typical flare will show an abrupt rise and a slower decay.

Comment: "This curvy"-- do you mean the cycle frequency is high, or the peak-peak ratio is large?

Comment: @RobJeffries, sure, here is the bigger image around 1326: https://imgur.com/a/MNLhqFj

Thank you so much!

Comment: Still not zoomed in enough to see what is going on.